# minimum value of $2$ variable expression

Tags: calculus

> If $\displaystyle g(a)=\sum^{n}_{i=1}\bigg(y_{i}-1-ax_{i}+2x_{i}\bigg)^2$ and $$\sum^{n}_{i=1}x_{i}=-5,\sum^{n}_{i=1}y_{i}=5,\sum^{n}_{i=1}x^2_{i}=15,\sum^{n}_{i=1}x_{i}y_{i}=10.$$ Finding value of $a$ for which $g(a)$ is minimum

What i try::$$g(a)=\sum^{n}_{i=1}\bigg[x_{i}(2-a)+y_{i}-1\bigg]^2$$

$$=(2-a)^2\sum^{n}_{i=1}x^2_{i}+\sum^{n}_{i=1}y^2_{i}+\sum^{n}_{i=1}1+2(2-a)\sum^{n}_{i=1}x_{i}y_{i}-2\sum^{n}_{i=1}y_{i}-2(2-a)\sum^{n}_{i=1}x_{i}$$

$$g(a)=15(2-a)^2+\sum^{n}_{i=1}y^2_{i}+n+20(2-a)-10+10(2-a)$$

I did not understand How do i minimize $g(a)$

If only $a$ present . Then we have easily minimize it using derivative. But due to $y_{i}$ , I did not understand how i minimize it. Help me . Thanks

Comment: That, at the end, should be $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i^2$.

Comment: If you need to minimize $g(a)$ as a function of $a$ only you can treat the $x_i$'s and $y_i$'s as constants or parameters. Then simply differentiate with respect to $a$.